# GCP : Classic LoadBalancer with single IP for ports 80 and 443

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I am working on managing one of the instance on GCP. We have a domain with UnitedDomains, where we can add a single IP address pointing to our domain. 
Unfortunately, GCP is providing us with 2 IP addresses when we are creating a load-balancer, one for port-80, another one for port-443.

Now, if I add the IP address of port-80 in domain mappings, then port-443 doesn't work as the IP is completely different and vice-versa.

I also tried adding a redirect in Nginx, and in a single block listen to both port80 and 443... Doesn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Nginx code :

```
server {
        listen   80;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name NAME;
        ssl on;
       }
```

Comment: I'm not following the idea that we would have two IP addresses for a load balancer because we have two desired target ports.  Can you elaborate on that?  Let us question the idea that we would have different IPs as a function of different ports.  I would imagine that I would be able to create a load balancer that could route to any number of ports.

Comment: Two different IP addresses is a common mistake when creating an IP address for the load balancer while in the screens creating the load balancer. Delete the frontends and recreate the frontends selecting the same IP address for each. Then delete the extra IP address.